Liquibase update stuck on "Executing on Database: database url"
I am quite stuck with a problem with liquibase. I am trying to connect to my oracle db and run my liquibase changelog.
The command I am running is as follows:
mvn clean verify [flag that clarifies which db i use] liquibase:update  -Dliquibase.url=db url  -Dliquibase.username=username  -Dschema=schema  -Dliquibase.password=password  -Dliquibase.changeLogFile=path to changelog
It runs just fine, but gets stuck on the line "Executing on Database: database url". I added debug flag to the command and it shows, that liquibase actually gets stuck on "Changelog query completed.".
Please help me fix it. Thank you!
(Sorry for my english, I am not native)

I tried using terminal to run the command, but the outcome is still the same.
I also tried checking connection to the database and it works just fine!
As I wrote above I tried adding the debug flag and it resulted in some progress
I also tried googling, but didn't find any help


Add liquibase.propertise file in the root of the project:
https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/connections/creating-config-properties.html
Then ensure you have set the paths accordingly, Also make sure you run the mcd in admin mode.
